# Rails activeadmin save data in associated table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin, has-many

I have one table for Products and the product can either be in the interior or exterior or both. So I created another table to save the Products location. Now when admin adds the product I have provided the option to select the location(s) the product can be in, but when it is posted the code says the field can't be blank because of the validation. I am not sure what I am missing or the approach is wrong.

**The product model:**

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord
  validates :name, presence: true      

  has_many :product_locations

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :product_locations
end
```

**The product location model:**

```
class ProductLocation < ApplicationRecord

  enum locations: [:exterior, :interior]

  validates :location, presence: true
  validates :product_id, presence: true

  belongs_to :product
end
```

**The ActiveAdmin file for Product:**

```
ActiveAdmin.register Product do

  permit_params :name, product_locations_attributes: {}

  actions :all, except: [:show, :destroy]

  filter :name

  index do        
    column 'Product Name',  :name
    actions
  end

  form do |f|
    f.semantic_errors *f.object.errors.keys

    f.inputs "Products" do
      f.input :name          
    end

    f.has_many :product_locations do |location|
      location.inputs "Locations" do
        location.input :location, as: :select, multiple: true, collection: ProductLocation.locations.keys
      end
    end

    f.actions
  end

  controller do
    def scoped_collection
      Product.where(user_id: nil)
    end
  end

end
```

I get a multi-select for the locations which has "Interior" and "Exterior" for selection, but it says the field can't be blank when I select the location and submit the form

The error on save click I get is:

> Location can't be blank

The params that get posted are:

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "product"=>{"name"=>"Test Product", "product_locations_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"location"=>["0", "1"]}}}, "commit"=>"Create Product"}
```

Comment: What is the exact error? Update it in the question.

Comment: @Pavan please check

Comment: I guess you should change `permit_params :name, product_locations_attributes: {}` to `permit_params :name, product_locations_attributes: [:location]`

Comment: I think this line, `location.input :location, as: :select, multiple: true, collection: ProductLocation.locations.keys` shoud be `location.input :location, as: :select, multiple: true, collection: ProductLocation.locations` since the `.keys` will not be present for array

Comment: @Pavan, but then it says "Unpermitted parameter: :location"

Comment: My mistake. It should be `permit_params :name, product_locations_attributes: [location: []]` as you have multiple select.

Comment: @Pavan It saves the data if I keep the it normal select, if I mark it as multiple select, then it gives the error. Is there anything else that needs to be done?

Comment: normal select with `location: []` or `:location`?

Comment: @Pavan with either of the options..

Comment: Can you update the question with the params generated with the original code?

Comment: @Pavan Please check

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145842/discussion-between-pavan-and-deepanshu-goyal).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, the **permit attributes** should be,

**`product_locations_attributes: [:id, :location]`**

Then, in your form

```
location.input :location, as: :select, multiple: true, collection: ProductLocation.locations.keys
```

Since `ProductLocation.locations` is an array, **`array.keys` is an invalid method.**

So, use directly

```
location.input :location, as: :select, multiple: true, collection: ProductLocation.locations.map { |n| [n,n] }
```

**To store an array of multiple values take `serialize` field as an array,**

```
class ProductLocation < ApplicationRecord

  enum locations: [:exterior, :interior]

  serialize :location, Array

  validates :location, presence: true
  validates :product_id, presence: true

  belongs_to :product
end
```

**Note:** Inorder to get the serialize work, you need to have the `dataType` of the location as a `text`. If it is not `text` run a migration to change to `text` data type

**Reason for text field:** Rails will convert all those object into plain text when storing in database

Comment: @DeepanshuGoyal, you should have your field type as `serialize` to store multiple values

Comment: I get this error: "can't dump `section`: was supposed to be a Array, but was a Integer. -- 0"

Comment: ok ,got it, change the colelction to, `ProductLocation.locations.map { |n| [n,n] }`

Comment: But it still gives me the error "can't dump section: was supposed to be a Array, but was a Integer. -- 0"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145848/discussion-between-deepanshu-goyal-and-sravan).